# How to display rows containing special characters in a certain column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the column `f_Name`. The column `f_name` sometimes contains special characters and numbers as in the examples below:

```
f_name
-----------
Pan23's 
Ram'kumar
lawer"s()
```

I want to retrieve all the values of `f_name` which have a special character or number.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  I apologize, but I don't understand what you mean by *special characters*.  None of the characters identified in your question look like they even fall outside of the standard ASCII character set.  Are you trying to output text as UNICODE rather than ASCII?  If so, you're going to need to include a [mcve] as the question in it's current form is too vague to understand, let alone answer with any level of accuracy.

Comment: If special characters are number(`0-9`) and these characters (`'"`) than you could write `select F_name from yourtable WHERE F_name LIKE '%[0-9''"]%`.  (watch it!: there are two single quotes here!).   If special characters are also other characters, than please `edit` your question.

Comment: So perhaps you should be looking for values that are not within A-Z,a-z? But a sample size of three is not a safe way to determine what logic you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
SELECT F_name  FROM tablename WHERE F_name LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```

What this does is search for

```
%.....% : a string
[.....] : that contains any of the mentioned characters 
^       : well actually none of the mentioned characters
a-Z     : from lower-case a through to upper-case Z
0-9     : or any digit
```

Which results in a search for any character other than `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`.
Strings that match this would be:

```
test'user
something?else
I#can#fly
```

<sup>***Reference:*** [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)</sup>

After re-reading your question, I would use just:

```
SELECT F_name  FROM tablename WHERE F_name LIKE '%[^a-Z]%'
```

...because you want to retrieve rows with numbers too.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. It helps if you can explain what you are actually answering. The community as a whole benefits and it shows the person that asked the question, that you have some understanding of the material you are trying to teach. Increasing the quality of the content also has the nice side-effect that the answer (or question for that fact) doesn't show up in the **low-quality moderation queue**. I have taken the liberty of adding an extended explanation of what your answer actually achieves. Feel free to [edit] to you requirements. Have a nice time on the network.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use I will remember that all things thanks for my answer more understanding